# Chrome extension load page in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load a page in the background to check to see if some information on it has changed. If it has changed, then I want to do something with it like alert the user. However, I'm having trouble loading the page to start with. Is it possible to load in the background? (I know that the Page Monitor extension must work in a similar fashion.)

I was originally thinking that the background.html page can be used to load the page and this wouldn't be seen by the user. But I can't load anything into that.

Also, having something like...

```
"background": {
  "page": ["http://www.google.com"],
  "persistent": true
 }
```

in the manifest isn't allowed by chrome. So would you have to inject the site into the background page?

Comment: That's not what [background pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) are for. Would an ordinary XHR work for your use case?

Comment: @sowbug I'm not exactly sure how XHRs work but I'd imagine that would be good